# Oracle: Data migration from 10-th x32 Enterprise to 11-th x64 Express

Tags: oracle, data-migration

I have dump of a Schema, done with `exp` under DBA, from Ora 10 Win x32. 
Now I'd like to move it to Oracle 11 Express x64.  Should I be able to restore this dump on Ora 11 Express?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is YES, it worked, no problem.
I expected much more problems installing x64 Oracle on my Windows 7.
But, eventually, it was very smooth and painless.